# UI is not updated when data in StateFlow changed in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a viewmodel like this

```
class CartViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val fireBaseRepository = FireBaseRepository.get()
private val cartRepository = CartRepository.get()
private val _cartState = MutableStateFlow(CartState())
val cartState: StateFlow<CartState> = _cartState.asStateFlow()

init {
    getCart()
}
private fun getCart() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        cartRepository.getCart().collect {cartItems ->
            cartItems.forEach { cart ->
                fireBaseRepository.getFood(
                    foodId = cart.foodId
                ) {
                   _cartState.value.foodItems += it
                }
            }
            _cartState.value = _cartState.value.copy(
                cartItems = cartItems,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

}

And the cartState

```
data class CartState(
var cartItems: List<CartItemData> = emptyList(),
var foodItems: List<FoodData> = emptyList())
```

My problem is that the UI is not listening to the updated data in the foodItems, however, the UI can receive the updates in the cartItems.

I found that my UI can't listen to the data change if I update foodItems inside cartRepository.getCart().collect{}, but I don't know why this happens.

I tried this code and my UI can listen to the updates in foodItems, so I'm sure that my getFood function is written correctly.

```
init {
    val foodId = listOf("fo01", "fo02","fo03")
    foodId.forEach { id ->
        fireBaseRepository.getFood(
            foodId = id,
            onGetFoodSuccess = {food ->
                _cartState.value.foodItems += food
            }
        )
    }
}
```

My composable function

```
fun CartScreen(
navController: NavController,
cartViewModel: CartViewModel = viewModel()) {
val cartState by cartViewModel.cartState.collectAsState()
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        CartScreenTopBar(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
        ) {
        }
    }
) { padding ->
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Ivory)
            .padding(padding)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.my),
                style = TextBoldStyle,
                fontSize = 32.sp
            )
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.cart_list),
                style = TextNormalStyle,
                fontSize = 32.sp
            )
        }
        LazyColumn(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            if (cartState.foodItems.isNotEmpty()) {
                items(cartState.cartItems) {cartItem ->
                    val food = cartState.foodItems.find { it.id == cartItem.foodId }
                    Log.d(TAG, food.toString())
                    food?.let {
                        CartItem(
                            cartItemData = cartItem,
                            foodData = it
                        )
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I also tried this to check if my UI can listen to the data change, but nothing was visible in the UI.

```
items(cartState.foodItems) {
                Text(text = it.name!!)
            }
```

Comment: Can you add the compose part ?  Are you collecting or using asState?

Comment: I added my composable function. Please have a look at my code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything strange in the code, but you can consider this possibility and try it.

StateFlow works by detecting when a new copy is created to replace
the data within it.  If you change the existing list, StateFlow may
not detect the change, thinking that the reference of the list is the
same, and therefore may not update the ui.

Please try like this maybe it will work.

```
private fun getCart() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        cartRepository.getCart().collect { cartItems ->
            val updatedFoodItems = mutableListOf<FoodData>()

            cartItems.forEach { cart ->
                fireBaseRepository.getFood(
                    foodId = cart.foodId
                ) { food ->
                    updatedFoodItems += food
                }
            }

            _cartState.value = _cartState.value.copy(
                cartItems = cartItems,
                foodItems = updatedFoodItems
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to fix my code like your but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried to edit my code from `_uiState.update {
            it.copy(
                courseTypes = _uiState.value.courseTypes?.onEach {
                    it.selected = futureSelected
                }
            )
        }` to `_uiState.update {
            it.copy(
                courseTypes = _uiState.value.courseTypes?.map {
                    it.copy(selected = futureSelected)
                }
            )
        }` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You're updating the list in the old state (that compose is keeping in its last snapshot), then emitting a new copy of that old state.

When compose does its comparison, it sees the old state (including the updated list) and no difference with the new state.

(This is one of the reasons I really prefer using immutable state with Compose - mutable state allows tricky little things like this happen)

If you change

```kotlin
cartRepository.getCart().collect {cartItems ->
    cartItems.forEach { cart ->
        fireBaseRepository.getFood(
            foodId = cart.foodId
        ) {
           _cartState.value.foodItems += it
        }
    }
    _cartState.value = _cartState.value.copy(
        cartItems = cartItems,
    )
}
```

to something like

```kotlin
cartRepository.getCart().collect {cartItems ->
    var newFoodItems = _cartState.value.foodItems
    cartItems.forEach { cart ->
        fireBaseRepository.getFood(
            foodId = cart.foodId
        ) {
           newFoodItems += it
        }
    }
    _cartState.value = CartState(
        cartItems = cartItems,
        foodItems = newFoodItems
    )
}
```

I believe it will do what you'd like. (And you could make the properties of CartState vals instead)

FYI - you should be able to simplify things a bit by using map() on the cart instead of collecting and emitting (untested but should be close):

```kotlin
class CartViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val fireBaseRepository = FireBaseRepository.get()
    private val cartRepository = CartRepository.get()

    val cartState = cartRepository.getCart().map() { cartItems ->
        var newFoodItems = _cartState.value.foodItems
        cartItems.forEach { cart ->
            fireBaseRepository.getFood(
                foodId = cart.foodId
            ) {
               newFoodItems += it
            }
        }
        CartState(
            cartItems = cartItems,
            foodItems = newFoodItems
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Before I posted this question, I tried modifying my code like yours, but it didn't work. If you look further into my code, you can see that I tested the state with the list of IDs and it was working fine. The UI can listen to the data change. It only doesn't work if I update the data of foodItems in the getCart() function.